# Getting 'procedure entry point could not be located' when running MinGW compiled OpenCV project

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, g++, mingw

I'm working on some college projects that require me to use OpenCV to read some video frames, after developing some parts of the code I decided to compile and test. After figuring out that the VC16 binaries from opencv.org won't work with MinGW, I downloaded unofficial binaries from https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build for the 4.5.5 version and modified my compile command to:

```
g++ sequential_convolution.cpp -o seq.exe -I C:/opencv/opencv/build/include -L C:/opencv/opencv/build/x64/mingw/lib -lopencv_core455 -lopencv_videoio455 -lopencv_imgcodecs45
```

Where `C:/opencv/opencv` is the path to where I installed OpenCV from the official site (also version 4.5.5). Running that command successfully compiles but when I run `seq.exe` I get the following errors:

[First DLL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUfrd.png)

[Second DLL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf50Q.png)

I have set the path to the `C:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\mingw\bin` binary folder and the path to g++ to my `PATH` variable in Windows 10 but to no avail.

I am using OpenCV 4.5.5 and gcc version 12.2.0.

Comment: you'll probably need to build opencv yourself to match your mingw version

Comment: Right, thank you very much.. Been trying to compile it but I just might give up and go to Visual Studio, path of least resistance :D

Comment: You could just use msys2 to install MinGW and opencv using pacman and you will not have any compatibility problems between the compiler and the opencv it installs.